# Tabpy: function Deployment fails on Docker running Tabpy

Tags: python, docker, tableau-api, tabpy

I am trying to deploy function to tabpy server , but I am getting following error while executing :
client.deploy('add',add,'adding x and y')

I am getting following error :

---

### Overwriting existing file "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tabpy/tabpy_server/staging/endpoints/name/1" when saving query object
Error with server response. code=500; text={"message": "error adding endpoint", "info": "FileNotFoundError : [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tabpy/tabpy_server/staging/endpoints/name/1'"}

I am able to deploy if I run tabpy on my local machine , but running in docker is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can only deploy functions directly from Tabpy server. remote deployment is not possible.